# Why is Ubuntu 22.04 missing newer Tomcat packages?

Tags: package-management, tomcat, ubuntu-pro

I'm looking for information about finding, fixing, or understanding why Ubuntu 22.04 is missing "newer" Apache Tomcat 9 packages. Specifically, 22.04 only includes up to Tomcat 9.0.58. This is the same whether I use the default free packages or attach an Ubuntu Pro subscription. Tomcat is listed as included in the ESM offerings with Pro, yet no packages >9.0.58 are available. 9.0.58 is over two years old and [lacks fixes for many CVEs](https://tomcat.apache.org/security-9.html) (including [CVE-2023-44487](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2023-44487), the [significant](https://blog.cloudflare.com/zero-day-rapid-reset-http2-record-breaking-ddos-attack) problem in HTTP/2).

Am I missing something? Have I been unable to to find documentation regarding official support policies for Tomcat or other Apache software? Is my understanding of Ubuntu's 5-year LTS policy or Pro subscription flawed? I know major versions get locked, but bugfixes and point releases should be covered. I'd like to avoid needing to hand-maintain Tomcat using ZIP files and downloads, hence why I use Ubuntu (and Pro).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: Apache2 packages are in Main: They are maintained by Canonical engineers. Tomcat packages are in Universe: Their maintenance has always been a Community responsibility (you and me). The community not doing their part is why Pro's support for **some** Universe packages exists.